# Static variable corruption on shared library loading

Tags: c++, linux, qt, static-variables

Could anyone explain why loading shared library corrupts static variable?

- Output on Linux (AltLinux, openSUSE): 1 true 0
- Output on Windows (using MinGW): 1 true 1

Qt 5.3.1: https://github.com/ipostanogov/variables-destroyer

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 is ok also.

Comment: SO questions (and answers) should be self-contained, and make sense even if any links in them break...

Comment: @hyde You expect me to post here content of 9 files? Seriously? Anyway `improve this question` button is waiting for you.

Comment: Check out what is [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... Or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Also, you don't have to include everything to make question self-contained. In this case it would probably be enough to show how you initialize and print static variable, end how you load the shared library, and what files you actually have. Just imagine there is no link, and read your own question. Does it make sense to others?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform and compiler. One solution is to initialize this static variable as the expected value in your code.

Comment: In this case he must use std::list, as QList does not support initializers. and standard list can be initialized like std::list<int> Core::stdList = {41, 42}; But anyway, loading library is must not fluent of static variables.

Comment: There is no expected value. It is a simple example. Real-word program retrieves info from library and stores it in static variable.

Comment: @Serhiy: Why will not `QList<int> list(QList<int>()<<1<<2<<3)` work in this case?

Comment: @user2672165: Oh, yes, I do not use Qt containers too much.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, when you load shared library it has another Core copy (with the empty list). and after loading shared lib you can access to the second copy, or this static list was initialized the second time (again, it will be empty after loading library). Try to compare this list addresses before and after the library was loaded, and you will get an answer.
Anyway it seems that problem is in the using two instances of a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the dynamic library is linked to the same Qt library you used to build the program. This shouldn't be an issue because QT is binary compatible, however, I see this error a lot on windows where we switched to a newer compiler (mingw 4.8) with a different ABI. Maybe this is an effect you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior observed because Global Offset Table (GOT), which ld.so using for init executable  image. In fact, static field in the above example initialized twice. First time during executable loading, second time during library loading. "static_initialization_and_destruction" proc calls from ld.lib's "dl_init_internal" procedure.